# Generalizing Random Forest: Stratified Feature Subspace Sampling

Tags: sampling, random-forest

The following would be a simple implementation of stratified subspace Random Forest. The basic idea for High Dimensional Random Forest is to use Subspace Feature Selection. I just am at a lose as how to blend these two components together.

```
############# DATA ##################
```

```r
german_credit <- read.table("http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning- 
databases/statlog/german/german.data")

colnames(german_credit) <- c("chk_acct", "duration", 
                         "credit_his", "purpose", "amount", 
                         "saving_acct", "present_emp", 
                         "installment_rate", "sex", 
                         "other_debtor", 
                         "present_resid", "property", "age", 
                         "other_install", "housing", "n_credits", 
                         "job", "n_people", "telephone", 
                         "foreign", "response")

german_credit$response <- german_credit$response - 1
german_credit$response <- as.factor(german_credit$response)
########## /DATA ##################

library(doParallel) 
library(VariableScreening)

random_forest <- function(train_data, train_formula, 
         method="class", feature_per=0.7, cp=0.01, 
min_split=20, min_bucket=round(min_split/3), max_depth=30, 
        ntrees = 10) {

target_variable <- as.character(train_formula)[[2]]
features <- setdiff(colnames(train_data), target_variable)
n_features <- length(features)

ncores <- detectCores(logical=FALSE)
cl <- makeCluster(ncores)
registerDoParallel(cl)

rf_model <- foreach(
  icount(ntrees),
  .packages = c("rpart", "Metrics")
  ) %dopar% {

bagged_features <- sample(features, n_features * feature_per, 
          replace = FALSE)
index_bag <- sample(nrow(train_data), replace=TRUE)

in_train_bag <- train_data[index_bag,]
out_train_bag <- train_data[-index_bag,]
trControl <- rpart.control(minsplit = min_split, 
       minbucket = min_bucket, cp = cp, maxdepth = max_depth)
tree <- rpart(formula = train_formula, data = in_train_bag, 
control = trControl)

oob_pred <- predict(tree, newdata = out_train_bag, 
              type = "class")
oob_acc <- accuracy(actual = out_train_bag[, target_variable], 
           predicted = oob_pred)
list(tree=tree, oob_perf=oob_acc)
}
 stopCluster(cl)
 rf_model
}

train_formula <- as.formula("response ~ .")
forest <- random_forest(train_data =german_credit, 
                train_formula = train_formula)
```

The component that needs to be replace is bagged_features but I cannot see how its even being used in this algorithm. The replacement basically does the following: Uses DCSIS to find the ranked variable importance. The Feature Subspace is segregated into Informative, Nil Informative and Non Informative Feature Subspaces. Then each subspace is sampled with different frequency. This will create more correlated trees which will require ensemble models to ensure diversity for each tree but that's future task.

```r
XStratFeat=function(X, Y, methodVS="DC-SIS", size=10, 
              COND=c(0.2,0.6), prob = c(.5, .3, .2)){ 
SCREEN<- screenIID(X,Y, method=methodVS)
XNUM=ncol(X); VARIMP<-SCREEN$rank          
     #### Rank Number of Variable Importance 

COND1=floor(XNUM*COND[1])
COND2=floor(XNUM*COND[2])

INFORM <- X.train[, VARIMP<COND1]
NilINFORM <- X.train[, (VARIMP>=COND1 && VARIMP<COND2)]
NonINFORM <- X.train[, VARIMP>=COND2]

set_id <- sample(c(1, 2, 3), size=size, replace = T, prob =prob)
SubSet=function(X, NUM){sample(ncol(X),
size=min(ncol(X), length(set_id[set_id==NUM])), replace=FALSE)}

 INSUB <- INFORM[, SubSet(X=INFORM, NUM=1)]
 NilINSUB <- NilINFORM[, SubSet(X=NilINFORM, NUM=2)]
 NONINSUB <- NonINFORM[, SubSet(X=NonINFORM, NUM=3)]
return(cbind(INSUB, NilINSUB, NONINSUB))}
```